# Output a resource table inside of a custom Laravel Nova Tool

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

What I'm trying to build:

A custom tool, where, I can have 4 buttons at the top of the page. Then, when a user clicks a button, it will load an index type table, similar to a Nova resource table.

For example: A user could click on the "Widgets" button and it would load a "Widgets" resource table below. Next, the user could click on the "Doodah" button and it would then, instead, load the "Doodah" table below. ... My main question is if there's a way to just harness what's already written in Nova and import it into my custom tool.

Comment: Update: I've found the route /nova-api/{resource} will return the appropriate data. I've also found the resource-table component will display said data. Now, it's a matter of wiring up the other events.

Comment: Did you come up with a working solution?

Answer (score -2):

The simplest solution is to add a router-link with the resource details inside the `navigation.blade.php` like this

```
:to="{
    name: 'index',
    params: {
        resourceName: 'your resource urlKey',
     },
}"
```